# Why does the pic option get passed through to the entire object?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

## Description

This question follows from the question [Why is the decoration marker off center?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307936/42748) where we found what was causing the problem, but not *why* it was being caused in the first place.

It seems that when placing the object `o2` **above** the pic `o1` the `above` option is getting passed through to the decorations in the `o2` object. This is the hypothesis because when we place the object `o2_2` **at** a node that is above `o1_2` then the decorations are drawn as expected.

## Example Image

[image: Comparison of the two methods]

## Semi-minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit,decorations.markings,patterns}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % remove page numbering to get good cropping when using pdfcrop

\def\pnode [#1]#2{
    % node for the potential function
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4, minimum size=5.0pt,fill=black,#1] (#2) {};
}
\def\snode [#1]#2#3{
    % node for the state variables
    \node[circle, minimum size=35.0pt , fill=lightgray,line width=0.625pt, draw=black,#1](#3){#2};
}
\def\osnode [#1]#2#3{
    % for for observed state variables
    \node[circle, minimum size=35.0pt , fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3},line width=0.625pt, draw=black,#1](#3){#2};
}
\tikzset{
    set midblock/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/midblock}{#1}},
    set midblock={name/.initial=b1},
    midblock/.style={
        set midblock={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\pnode[]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/midblock/name}}}}
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{
    pics/object1/.style 2 args={
       code={
        \begin{scope}
            \snode[]{obj-1}{-i};
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{
    pics/object2/.style 2 args={
       code={
        \begin{scope}[rotate=#2, transform shape]
            \snode[]{obj-2}{-i};
            \snode[right = of -i]{j-txt}{-j};
            \snode[above = of -i]{k-txt}{-k};
            \snode[left = of -i]{l-txt}{-l};
            \draw[midblock={name=foo}] (-i)--(-j);
            \draw[midblock={name=baz}] (-j)--(-k);
            \draw[midblock={name=bar}] (-k)--(-l);
            \draw[midblock={name=bar}] (-l)--(-i);
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Broken Code ...  but why?
    \path pic (o1) {object1};
    \pic [above= of o1-i] (o2) {object2={}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace {2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % This code works
    \path pic (o1_2) {object1};
    \snode[above=of o1_2-i]{}{n1};
    \pic (o2_2) at (n1) {object2={}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## ******EDIT******

As requested a more minimal example.

## Image

[image: More minimal Example]

## The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit,decorations.markings,patterns}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % remove page numbering to get good cropping when using pdfcrop

\def\pnode [#1]#2{
    % node for the potential function
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4, minimum size=5.0pt,fill=black,#1] (#2) {};
}
\def\snode [#1]#2#3{
    % node for the state variables
    \node[circle, minimum size=35.0pt , fill=lightgray,line width=0.625pt, draw=black,#1](#3){#2};
}

\tikzset{
    set midblock/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/midblock}{#1}},
    set midblock={name/.initial=b1},
    midblock/.style={
        set midblock={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\pnode[]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/midblock/name}}}}
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{
    pics/object1/.style 2 args={
       code={
        \begin{scope}
            \snode[]{obj-1}{-i};
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{
    pics/object2/.style 2 args={
       code={
        \begin{scope}[rotate=#2, transform shape]
            \snode[]{obj-2}{-i};
            \snode[right = of -i]{j-txt}{-j};
            \draw[midblock={name=foo}] (-i)--(-j);
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Broken Code ...  but why?
    \path pic (o1) {object1};
    \pic [above= of o1-i] (o2) {object2={}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace {2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % This code works
    \path pic (o1_2) {object1};
    \snode[above=of o1_2-i]{}{n1};
    \pic (o2_2) at (n1) {object2={}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The current implementation of `pic`s is demonstrably buggy. For example, some code from the manual simply doesn't work in the current version of PGF/TikZ. (It used to work.) I don't know if this is a bug or expected behaviour, but don't be surprised if it is the former.

Comment: Can you really not demonstrate the problem with a more minimal example? If you really want help with diagnosis, it is going to have to be reduced to a more manageable tangle.

Answer (score 1):

`\pic[above= of o1-i]...`
→ `\path pic[above= of o1-i]...`
→ `node[above= of o1-i]...`
→ `\tikzset{above= of o1-i}`
→ `\def\tikz@anchor{south}`

Keeping this in mind, your problem can be solved by assigning explicit anchor to `\pnode`. That is, you just need to replace

> ```
> \pnode[]
> ```

by

> ```
> \pnode[anchor=center]
> ```

and everything works as expected.