# Nested tikz pics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I have a basic pic ("brick") that I rotate/flip/shift within other pics (e.g. "wall").
These pics ("wall") then get drawn in my tikzpicture, possibly themselves rotated/flipped/shifted.

The brick pic renders fine, the wall pic renders fine, but I cannot seem to scale or rotate the wall pic (I can shift it with `xshift` and `yshift` though).

I have followed [this nested pics question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215580/nested-pics-in-tikz-3-0) which was resolved by replacing the `\draw` in the wall pic with `\path`.
However, that question did not deal with rotations and scalings.

How can I rotate/scale my `wall` pic? At the moment my ugly workaround is to put the tikz for `brick` into a macro which I call in the wall code (as opposed to drawing the brick pic), but this does not seem to be the tikz way.

[image]

In the above, shifting the wall works (blue), but the x-mirrored wall (red) does not mirror. (Obviously not intended to be bricks and walls, unless I am constructionally challenged).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  brick/.pic={
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 3) -- (2, 1.5) -- cycle;
  },
  wall/.pic={
    \path pic {brick};
    \path pic [xshift=1cm,yshift=2cm,scale=0.5] {brick};
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3, -1) rectangle (3, 4);% bounding box
  \node at (0, 0) {.}; % origin

  \draw pic {wall};
  % scaling does not work
  \path pic [red,ultra thin,xscale=-1] {wall};
  % shifting works
  \path pic [blue,ultra thin,xshift=1cm] {wall};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had such an [issue before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324403/110998), and it was recommended to use `pics` (see comments below post). It turned out that mirroring doesn't work with `pics`.

Comment: Need `transform shape`.

Comment: @Symbol1 thanks so much! I put `transform shape` into the tikzpiture `\path pic`, and it worked. (I think I'll `every node/.style={transform shape}`). If you would like to post it as an answer I can mark the question as closed. Otherwise I'll post your answer as an answer (for posterity) tomorrow some time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is somewhat related to [Why does the pic option get passed through to the entire object?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308056/why-does-the-pic-option-get-passed-through-to-the-entire-object/341406#341406)

Drawing a pic is essentially drawing a node, so everything you know about node applies. For example: a node is not rotated/scaled but only shifted. However a node is rotated/scaled if you said `transform shape`. And this is indeed the answer to your question.

To clarify:

```
% does not work
\path pic [red,ultra thin,xscale=-1] {wall};
% works
\path pic [red,ultra thin,xscale=-1,transform shape] {wall};
```

To make things easier, one could add `[every node/.style=transform shape]` into the tikzpicture options or similar.